# Amazon application testing environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just playing around with a post to Amazon module and want to know if Amazon has anything similar to ebay sandbox?

Comment: Is there a specific web service you're referring to? Some services have a sandbox (e.g. FPS), but most things that people call "AWS" do not -- you instead test things by actually launching EC2 instances, creating SQS queues, pushing SNS notifications, etc. on the production infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general sandbox. I took a class from Amazon where they used a third party service that created separate AWS accounts with a small budget for each student. Using real accounts and real money seems to be the only way to do it.